# How to select specific rows in a data set (R)

Tags: r

I have a data set containing some information about certain US states. The row names are states' names.

[image]

I want to select several states' (i.e. "AL" and "CA") information and create a new data set, but how?

Comment: You can use `which` in R, or you can use the method here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576138/how-to-remove-rows-of-a-matrix-by-row-name-rather-than-numerical-index

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can form a vector of `rownames`

```
x <- c("AL", "CA" )
```

and then

```
df[x, ]
```

or directly

```
df[c("AL", "CA"), ]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df2 <- df[rownames(df) %in% c("AL", "CA"),]
```